# Most efficient way to group SQL Server results into easily-parsable result set

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data in a SQL Server database:

```
service_id  delivery_id  price_increase
----------  -----------  --------------
    1             1           0.4
    1             2           0.3
    1             3           0.2
    1             4           0.1
    1             5             0
    2             1           0.4
    2             2           0.3
    2             3           0.2
    2             4             0
    2             5             0
    4             1           0.5
    4             2           0.3
    4             3           0.25
    4             4           0.15
    4             5             0
```

Some points:

- all the `service_id` values will always have a full complement of `delivery_id` values (*i.e.*, there's a requirement to have `delivery_id`s 1-5)
- there doesn't have to be a full complement of `service_id` values (as you can see above, `service_id` 3 has no entry)
- for the purposes of this question, there's no limit on the number of `service_id` entries

These values will be parsed into the following class hierarchy:

```
ServicePricing
 - ServiceId
 - IEnumerable<DeliveryPricing>
```

where

```
DeliveryPricing
 - DeliveryId
 - PriceIncrease
```

What's the easiest way to query these values from the DB and then use C# to parse them? I *could* do it in a fairly trivial but tedious manner, checking to see whether a `service_id` has already been declared in code and so on, but is there any way to group the results so that I can more easily loop through them and have a clear boundary at which to declare a new instance of either of the classes?

For example, is it possible to put all results from the same `service_id` into an individual result set?

[Just for clarification, I'm looking for a SQL-based suggestion, not how to parse a result set in C#.]

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: do you want a result set for each different service_id ? or what is your question ?

Comment: @ChrisPickford - No, I'm not using EF. That would have made things very simple but like I said, I'm having to parse these results.

Comment: @GuidoG - If it's possible to have a different result set for each different `service_id` _and_ if that's the best solution, then yes. I'm looking to align the data - from the query - in such a way that makes parsing it into the described object hierarchy - in C# - as trivial as possible.

Comment: you could retrieve the different service_id with "select distinct service_id from yourtable" and than in c# loop through this collection and for every distinct service_id you alter the query you have now with "where service_id = " + distinctServiceID before you start the loop you already have now

Comment: but I would not do it like that i would loop through the whole set (ordered by service_id) and check when the service_id changes from its prior value. That would be much more efficient

Comment: Ok, that's what I was intending to do, just thought I'd ask to see if there was a way in which I could get SQL Server do some form of grouping/collating and offloading that logic into the query rather than dealing with it while parsing the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
select service_id,  delivery_id,  price_increase 
from table order by service_id,  delivery_id 

int? serviceID = null;
ServicePricing sp; 
List<ServicePricing> sps; 
while (rdr.Read())
{
   if(rdr.GetInt(0) <> serviceID)
   {
      if(sp != null) 
        sps.Add(sp);
      serviceID = rdr.GetInt(0);
      sp = new ServicePricing(serviceID); 
   }
   sp.DeliveryPricings.Add(new DeliveryPricing(rdr.GetInt(1), rdr.GetDecimal(2));
}
sps.Add(sp);
```

Comment: Thanks @Paparazzi but I did say that I did say "I'm looking for a SQL-based suggestion, not how to parse a result set in C#".